# C# convert all long variables to the string at one time

Tags: c#, .net

How to convert all long variable to string variable in all Class in one Project with 
C#?
One variable Can change:

```
long a = 123456789;
string str = a.ToString();
```

but how to change all?

Comment: What are you even asking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a general rule, if you want to do "stringy" things with a variable declare it as a string, if you want to do "longy" things with a variable declare it as an long, and so on...

To change all of your longs to strings you could do a "find and replace" - search for "long" and replace it with "string" and surround the digits with double quotes.

If you'd like to do it at run time you'd have to call `ToString()` on each of your longs when you encounter them - there is no way to do them all at once.